Finding CDF of function of random variables
I have two random variables $X$, $Y$ i.i.d. with CDF $F_X(x)=(1-x^{-4})\boldsymbol{1_{(1,  +\infty)}}(x)$ where $\boldsymbol{1_A}$ is the indicator function on a set $A$, and thus PDF $f_X(x)=4x^{-5}\boldsymbol{1_{(1,  +\infty)}}$.
I want to calculate the CDF of $Z=\log(XY)$, specifically by obtaining it from $F_Z(t)=P(Z \leq t)$. Usually, when I have a random vector $(X, Y)$ with PDF $f_{(X, Y)}$, if I want to calculate $P(X<Y)$ (for example) I can just compute $\int (\int ^y f_{(X, Y)}dx)dy$ with $Y$ as an upper bound for $X$ (and the others obviously depend by the exercise)
So I decided to build a random vector $(X,Y)$ with PDF
$$f_{(X,Y)}(x, y)=f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)=16x^{-5}y^{-5}\boldsymbol{1_{(1, +\infty)}}(x)\boldsymbol{1_{(1, +\infty)}}(y)$$
thanks to the hypothesis that $X$, $Y$ are independent, and then compute the CDF with
$$F_Z(t)=P(Z\leq t) = P(\log(XY)\leq t) = P(XY \leq e^t) = P(X \leq \frac{e^t}{Y}) = P(X \leq \frac{e^t}{Y}) =\\ \int ^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\int ^{\frac{e^t}{y}}_{-\infty}16x^{-5}y^{-5}\boldsymbol{1_{(1, +\infty)}}(x)\boldsymbol{1_{(1, +\infty)}}(y)dxdy = \\ \int ^{+\infty}_{1}\int ^{\frac{e^t}{y}}_{1}16x^{-5}y^{-5}dxdy$$
But, both doing it by hand and with wolfram alpha, this integral seems to not converge.
Where is the mistake?

Note that I want to understand what I'm doing wrong, which seems to be a conceptual mistake, not just finding the CDF of $Z$, because I already know that I can find it by using the fact that $Z=\log(XY)=\log(X)+\log(Y)$ with $\log(X), \log(Y) \sim Exp(4)$ and thus $Z \sim \Gamma(2, 4)$ where $Exp$ is the exponential distribution and $\Gamma$ the gamma distribution

An alternative way would be to compute
$$ F_Z(t) = P(Z\leq t) = P(\log(X) + \log(Y) \leq t) = P(\log(X) \leq t -  \log(Y)) =\\ \int ^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\int ^{t-y}_{-\infty}16e^{-4x}e^{-4y}\boldsymbol{1_{(0, +\infty)}}(x)\boldsymbol{1_{(0, +\infty)}}(y)dxdy = \\ \int ^{+\infty}_{0}\int ^{t-y}_{0}16e^{-4x}e^{-4y}dxdy$$ thanks to the fact that $\log(X), \log(Y) \sim Exp(4)$. But also this integral seems to diverge.

Your computations are almost correct, there is only a subtle error.
In order to have $XY\leq e^t$, given that $X\geq 1$ we must have $Y\leq e^t$.
Therefore, the correct integral should be $$F_Z(t)= \int ^{\color{red}{e^t}}_{1}\int ^{\frac{e^t}{y}}_{1}16x^{-5}y^{-5}\,dx\,dy=1-(4t+1)e^{-4t}$$
Differentiating, we find $$f_Z(t)=16te^{-4t},\,\,\,t>0$$
which is the pdf of a gamma distribution $\Gamma(2,4)$, as expected.
